# Does the Ready action give advantage if I attack while not seen?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage, reactions

As in the title, does the Ready action gives advantage if the prepared reaction is an attack performed while not seen (for example, while I am hidden)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the section on Unseen Attackers and Targets:

> When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

It doesn't matter what kind of action gives you the attack, if your target can't see you, you have advantage.